# Can you create user on GCP with terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

Hey I'm trying to create new users in IAM on GCP and automate it with terraform, I know you can do so on AWS with the [`aws_iam_user`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_user.html) is there an equivalent on GCP ? I see the [`google_project_iam_member`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/google_project_iam.html) but it doesn't create a new user but expects one to be there already.

PS error message looks like this

```
Error: Request "Create IAM Members roles/storage.objectViewer 
user:tom@example.com for \"project \\\"<my-project-id>\\\"\"" returned 
error: Error applying IAM policy for project "<my-project-id>": Error 
setting IAM policy for project "<my-project-id>": googleapi: Error 400: 
User tom@example.com does not exist., badRequest
```

and the code is simply

```sh
provider "google" {
  credentials = file(var.credentials)
  project = var.project_name
  region  = var.region
}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "member" {
  project = var.project_id
  role    = "roles/storage.objectViewer"
  member  = "user:tom@example.com"
}
```

Comment: I believe the user is just any email with an associated google account. You can make service accounts programatically, but I expect a google account for a person would requite a captcha or similar.

Comment: hmmm that makes sense I'll try making dummy gmail account and adding it

Comment: Oh my god, you're a genius

Answer (score 1):

Well this is awkward or maybe not and just my mis-interpretation. You don't really create user - the user is just an Google account user - with it's own password, associated phone etc. - you cannot create new user on gcp (google) - you can merely allow existing user to have some role on your GCP project/organization.

PS: kudos to @Hitobat for suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You need another provider for admin.google.com tasks:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/googleworkspace/latest/docs

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31907790)